# AWS S3 permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a bucket name "A" with following permissions:

```
1. Grantee: B  List  Update/delete

2. Grantee: Everyone  List  view/download
```

From IOS(front-end), they are uploading a video to this Bucket.After uploaded only the 1st permission is applied, second is not, So we nobody can download that video from S3.

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of entity is `B`?  Without more detail, I suspect that the object is being uploaded with a different AWS account as the owner of the object, or with "the anonymous user" (e.g. nobody) as the owner, and in either case it is actually *correct* that your second rule doesn't apply -- you don't own the object (even though it's in your bucket) thus the right for anyone to download it is not technically yours to grant.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any `view/download` option in the **S3 Permissions** pane.

> As a general rule, AWS recommends using S3 bucket policies or IAM
>   policies for access control. S3 ACLs is a legacy access control
>   mechanism that predates IAM.

[AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/)

If you wish to use a bucket policy instead, you can do the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1420667647000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1420667680000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:user/username"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks in the above what are all i have to replace with mine,, `arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:user/username"`, user is mine, what is username?

Comment: @Subburaj: For example: `arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/Subburaj`. You can read more about specifying a principal in a policy here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html